# duplicate ‘extern’ in a Yacc-like parsers in C

Tags: c

```
#Bison implementation for Yacc-like parsers in C

y.tab.c:557:1: error: duplicate ‘extern’
 extern YYSTYPE yylval;
 ^
make[2]: *** [pat_decl_y.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/alliance-5.0/ppt/src'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/alliance-5.0/ppt'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

how do I fix this?
This is standard file. I don't know why generate an error like that.

Comment: The error generates because during your program you are declaring `extern YYSTYPE yylval;` more then once.

Comment: Yes, there are numerous independent folders. And each folder has a makefile and contain extern YYSTYPE yylval; The very top level has a makefile too.    I don't think I can get rid of  extern YYSTYPE yylval, there are too many of them.  50 independent folders.

Comment: What makes you think you can declare an extern more then once? Name them differently.

Comment: @Magisch: actually you can declare an extern more than once, it should be declared without extern exactly once in one of the linked modules. Assuming 'gcc' is used, the error says that the keyword 'extern' is used twice on the same variable (yylval). Look into y.tab.c. It is possible that YYSTYPE is a #define with 'extern' in it also.

Comment: Why do you have extern `yylval` in `y.tab.c` file? `yylval` is variable generated by `Yacc`, not extern variable.  Also, edit your question, explain your problem little bit more.

Comment: OK,  still throw me an error after I added the // which is a comment                                                                               .y.tab.c:557:1: error: duplicate ‘extern’
 //extern YYSTYPE yylval;
 ^
make[1]: *** [pat_decl_y.lo] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/lilzz/alliance-5.0/ppt/src'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
lilzz@lilzz-Latitude-E6400:~/alliance-5.0/ppt$

Answer (score 1):

You will get that error when you run it in alliance/src directory.

Build it in a separate directory like this:

```
mkdir your_alliance_top_directory/build
cd your_alliance_top_directory/build
../alliance/configure
```